# Закрытие всех активных соеденений

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Возможно ли отклонить все отправляющиеся запросы в текущий момент на странице с помощью JS? Вот допустим, мне нужно что бы запросы могли отправляться только 30 секунд, последующие блокировались. Такое сделать возможно? Не обязательно на JS, главное что б работало на веб-платформе.

Answer (score 1):

Задача имеет две подзадачи:

1. Как узнать каие запросы отправляются;
2. Как прервать выполняющийся запрос.

Часть ответа, касающаяся AJAX такова:

1. Нужно при отправке запросов сохранять ссылки на `XMLHttpRequest` объекты;
2. У объекта `XMLHttpRequest` есть метод `abort()`.

А вот если вам нужно обрывать соединения, которые созданы не вашим кодом, да еще и если это стили, скрипты, картинки, с этим сложнее (если вообще возможно).